# Determine model based on role

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, datamodel

I have a table where I save users. Users can either be a student, teacher, headmaster or a combination of this, I make use of roles to achieve this(package called [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)).

I provide specific models for students, teachers and headmasters with their own logic, queries and so on, but I don't have specific tables for these models.

Currently I determine if a user is a teacher by using the boot() function in the Teacher model (same goes for students and headmaster):

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        //Todo: make use of role package to determine if model is teacher or not.
        static::addGlobalScope('teacher', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('teacher_offering')
                    ->whereRaw('teacher_offering.user_id = users.id');
            });
        });
    }
```

This query works well, but I was wondering if I could simplify this by making use of the Laravel-permission package provided by Spatie.

My questions is: can I replace the query inside the boot() function by checking if the teacher role is assigned to the user?

Can I achieve this with this package or should I stay with this query?

Answer (score 0):

What's your use case for checking a user's role? If you're trying to prevent access to certain pages, use [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) to check roles. I don't think scopes are suitable for this.

The [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) package provides the `hasRole($role)` method, assuming your `User` implements the `HasRoles` trait:

```
$isTeacher = Auth::user()->hasRole('teacher');
```

Comment: Preventing access to certain pages is already covered by using the middleware provided by the package. 

The thing that I try to achieve is to make use of the teacher model if the user has the teacher role, because in the teacher model there are some specific functions that only need to be accessed by teachers and not other users.

Currently I check that by looking if a user is linked to a class in the database (in the boot() function of the teacher model). I want to change that to check if the user has the teacher role.

Does this make sense?

Comment: @Y.Jacobs Honestly, no. Enabling certain 'functions' (vaguely described) seems like something you would do in your Blade templates (eg. hiding certain forms or buttons) AND in your controllers (eg. using FormRequests), to ensure users with certain roles can or cannot access certain functions. So again, your model is not the place to program this logic.